# How to call or dial from my head unit through Bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, calls, automotive-head-unit

I just upgraded my head unit to Woodman Big B on Android 8.1. I'm not finding a good way to dial out someone from the head unit. I am connected to my mobile through Bluetooth.

How to call or dial from my head unit through Bluetooth?

Comment: Check the device on the Bluetooth setting. Used for ...?

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time today exploring my head unit and found that the Bluetooth app has the option for downloading contacts from the phone. Also, it has a nice dialer.